# Access - calling query from VBA vs direct execute

Tags: ms-access, vba, sharepoint-2013

I am baffled by this problem.  I have an Access 2013 database where most of the key tables are on SharePoint 2013 (not ideal but necessary). To allow the database to run faster, when the database opens, VBA code calls queries to download key SharePoint files to local tables. The main catalog table has 7300 records. This table takes over 30 seconds to populate the local table (by stepping through the code). If I run the query directly in the database, it takes 5 seconds at most.  What is going on that it takes so long with VBA??

Comment: You've said: `VBA code calls queries to download key SharePoint files to local tables`. Keyword: queries, plural form. Then: `by stepping through the code`. Debugger adds overhead, watches add overhead, etc. Usually neglible, but who knows. Then `If I run the query directly in the database, it takes 5 seconds at most`. Keyword: query. Singular. If that was not a typo, then please note that running 10 queries vs running 1 batch with 10 queries vs running 1 query is a **huge** difference in terms of network ops, data marshalling, query plan building, actual db ops, etc, all adding to total time.

Comment: ..but, it still all depends on what you do in VBA and how. For example, how do you fill the local tables? Is if as fast as it can be? If you `run the query directly in the database, it takes 5 seconds at most` then maybe the rest of, say, 20 seconds is spent on inserting rows to the local tables? Right now, as you wrote it, you've got "time to read=5s", and "time on network=?", and "time to write=?", and "time to read+network+write=30s" so pretty much you're comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: When I test the query through VBA, I put a breakpoint at that particular append query it is calling and step through it.  It takes 30+ seconds to get to the next query.  When I execute the append query in the database (double click or open, not datasheet view), it appends within the 5 seconds.